# Enable new GL rendering in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, webgl

Just recently Google made available Maps GL on the GMaps platform. We have an HTML5 app that's heavily maps based, and we'd love to try out the new map rendering that's based on WebGL. Already we're noticing the potential performance benefits.

Does anyone know how to switch API v3 to  Maps GL rendering or other ways to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL maps hasn't been added to the API yet so you cannot enable it.

Comment: Google doesn't give timelines on when features will be implemented. Your best bet is to go to the issue tracker and file a feature request for it and then you will be notified if/when it is done.

Answer (score 7):

I've opened up a feature request for this in the issues tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4131&thanks=4131&ts=1336609133