# Google Maps Javascript API tilt view differs from the one on www.google.com/maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I noticed that some places opened on [google.com/maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+Mark+Esplanade,+Rockville,+MD+20850,+USA/@39.0698984,-77.1568678,480a,35y,39.28t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89b7cd0f1cef07bb:0x2e2e9180abbb22ca!8m2!3d39.0764208!4d-77.155731) service look completely different from the same view generated using `Google Maps Javascript API 3` using `tilt: 45`.

> In the example map center is `lat`:`39.073282988412444` `lng`:`-77.15641707252614`

So how it looks on `google.com/maps` service using `hybrid` mode and `3d` view (not sure if it is the same as `tilt: "45"`):

[image]

And this is how it looks on my website using `Google Maps Javascript API 3` in `hybrid` mode with `tilt: 45` option:

[image]

As you can see the quality is poor when using API. Google maps uses something like 3d rendering which is not available through API.

**So my question is**. Does that mean that we (API customers) cannot achieve the same quality as we see on `google.com/maps` service? 
Because I believe everybody thinks that he can embed the same map as shown on google.com/maps through API, but in reality, it seems that you get lower quality service.

**PS:** I noticed that `google.com/maps` probably uses WebGL:

[image]

Comment: Seems it is not available in 2017 (like 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005254/6309). Maybe https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/ might help?

Comment: I'd be keen to hear from a credible source on this also (preferably Google). The answer to your question is that no, we cannot get the same results from the API as from Google Maps itself (this is not the only situation where they differ). It would be great to know a bit more about why, and if there is any kind of roadmap for when/if features might get brought into the API.

Comment: When I use the most simply map of the api (consult [google developer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=en)), we have the same resolution that in the official mapI do not no what is the tilt: 40 but I seems to be the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important point is that Google Maps JavaScript API and Google Maps consumer application (maps.google.com) are different products managed by different teams at Google. You shouldn't expect that they work exactly the same way at all situations. As far as I know the API team strives to get the functionality as much close to consumer application as possible, but sometimes they need some time to implement things on the API side.

Referring to the MapsGL support in the Google Maps JavaScript API, there is a feature request in Google issue tracker that currently has 130 stars. Please have a look at this feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821626

I would suggest starring the feature request to add your vote, hopefully Google will take into account the number of people who starred the issue and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, in "[Enable new GL rendering in Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005254/6309)", WebGL was unavailable in 2011.
In 2014, the [Web Maps JavaScript API Release Notes page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) shows with [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825289) that WebGL is active.

But the [Google Maps APIs documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) shows multiple APIs, and [an API picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)

From that API picker, we see that 3D features are only available in [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/).
It is *not* mentioned/available in the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) or [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/), used to embed a map in a web page.
Yet, that last API does show a view mode which displays buildings in a 3D-ish way: [Google Maps Embed API  / Map Mode / View mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#view_mode): maybe that is enough for your case. (IE, using the "Embed API", not the "Javascript API")

[image: embed map with 3D elements]